# How to hide first two elements of <dl> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hide

EDIT: 2
Forget it all, THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP! It was my issue to fix some other JS causing the problem. All good on all browsers.

---

Not sure I should do the edit here or start a new thread for this, but it is a follow on from my first ask for help.

The code provided by Roko (@user2469528) worked a treat so thank you, but it seems to be OK only in Chrome (which I use in checking my work) but not so in Firefox, IE and Safari  (I just noticed it!). So as an extension of my first query, would you help me understand why perhaps this is the case? Is is a JQuery issue?

To see it in action, please go to [the site I am building](http://www.itoutlet.com.au/) (BigCommerce back end) then add products to the cart, view the cart, then click on "Calculate Shipping Cost". Since this site will only sell in Aus I have hidden the Country and State drop downs from this menu. Perfect in Chrome (current version at least!) but not so in FF / Safari / IE10...

Thanks again for any input!
M

Original request *****************************************

I am trying to hide the first two `<dt>` and `<dd>` of a non named list. The list is inside of a named `div` though, per below.

```
<div class="ShippingMethod">
   <dl>
      <dt>Country</dt>                     <--- Hide
      <dd>Country List</dd>                <--- Hide 
      <dt>State</dt>                       <--- Hide
      <dd>State List</dd>                  <--- Hide
      <dt>Post Code</dt>
      <dd>Post Code List</dd>
   </dl>
</div>
```

There are other `<dl>` on the page so I need to target this particular instance inside the div with "ShippingMethod" class. I have tried a few combinations of code from this forum without success.

Comment: Can there be multiple DIVs with this class?

Comment: Hi Barmar, there isn't in this case. Good question though and perhaps I should have specified... Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Usually class is used when there may be multiple, ID is used when something is unique.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks for the input, but after all, the solution has not worked across all browsers. Please see my amended post, and thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: I tried your page in Safari and it seems to work. When I click on Calculate Shipping Cost it just displays the Postcode field.

Comment: Also worked in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/uciyiv/1/edit <-- demo with multiple elements with same class `.ShippingMethod`

```
$('.ShippingMethod').find('dt:lt(2), dd:lt(2)').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

> Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

Comment: Your second selector isn't specific enough -- there's nothing tying it to `.ShippingMethod"`.

Comment: Roko, genius, THANK YOU!

Comment: @Barmar cause it's not needed at all, if you take a look at the documentation, it's all there.

Comment: SO answers should not just be pointers to documentation, they should include concrete examples showing how to apply it to the particular case.

Comment: Hi @user2469528 Roko, see my amended post (if you have time!). Not sure why it is not working across all browsers? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user2469528 when you want to reference a message to someone, don't do it for yourself but like `@RokoCBuljan` otherwise that person will not be notified about your comment. The code I provided you works perfectly crossbrowser. You might have issues elsewhere. What says console?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ShippingMethod dl dt:lt(2), .ShippingMethod dl dd:lt(2)").hide();
```

Comment: Your code `$(".ShippingMethod dl dt:lt(2), .ShippingMethod dl dd:lt(2)").hide();` will not work with multiple class `ShippingMethod` which is usually why we use classes, right ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$(".ShippingMethod dl dt:lt(2), .ShippingMethod dl dt:lt(2)").hide();
```

Or using a more efficient way with `slice()`:

```
$(".ShippingMethod dl dt, .ShippingMethod dl dd").slice(0,4).hide();
```

Comment: Second one should be `.slice(0, 3)` I think.

Comment: @Barmar I think `(0, 4)` actually, 2 of each `dd` and `dt`.